# How to use xpath to find a text node

Tags: xpath, scrapy, web-crawler, lxml

[image]

I'm using scrap to get user informations on stack overflow. And I try to use `//h2[@class="user-card-name"]/text()[1]` to get that name. However I get this:

```
['\n                            Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams\n                            \n
```

Someone plz help.

Comment: This one is definitely @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams's problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to clean up surrounding whitespaces from the result easily using Python's `strip()` function :

```
In [2]: result = response.xpath('//h2[@class="user-card-name"]/text()[1]').extract()

In [3]: [r.strip() for r in result]
Out[3]: [u'Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams']
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way when crawling unstructured data with scrapy is to use ItemLoaders, and [`scrapylib`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapylib) offers some very good `default_input_processor` and `default_output_processor`.

**items.py**

```
from scrapy import Item, Field
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapylib.processors import default_input_processor
from scrapylib.processors import default_output_processor

class MyItem(Item):
    field1 = Field()
    field2 = Field()

class MyItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = MyItem

    default_input_processor = default_input_processor
    default_output_processor = default_output_processor
```

now on your spider code, populate your items with:

```
from myproject.items import MyItemLoader


...
... # on your callback


    loader = MyItemLoader(response=response)
    loader.add_xpath('field1', '//h2[@class="user-card-name"]/text()[1]')

    ... keep populating the loader

    yield loader.load_item() # to return an item
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = response.xpath('//h2[@class="user-card-name"]/text()').extract()
result = result[0].strip() if result else ''
```